# How to connect to private rds in network load balancer and ecs with mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs

[image]

My AWS Architecture is like the image.
My professor suggested me make public rds into private rds.
I did it. But I don't know how to open it with mysql workbench.
Thanks for any help.

ecs : task definition with ec2
rds : Aurora-mysql 
security group : load balancer security group
[image]

[image]

[image]

I put SSH hostname as load balancer DNS name which is my website name.
SSH Username : ec2-user 
and SSH Key file with the key-pair. 
This doesn't work well.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Bastion host in public subnet in the same VPC with your RDS and use it at a Jump server.

For detail, you can follow this blog:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-ssh-workbench-connect-ec2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the third option here, by just adding an NLB and managing the access with security groups, you do not strictly need a bastion host.
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/connecting-rds-db-private-subnet-aws-from-using-ssm-port-srinivasan/